# How to calculate the speed of a jet of liquid coming out of a nozzle?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension, bernoulli-equation

I'm working on a project and i need to calculate speed of a jet falling from a nozzle.

But my question is that, is it correct to use

$$v=\sqrt{2gh}$$

Or should the speed of the jet be independent of the radius of the nozzle due to Bernoulli's equation?

Comment: Your question asks an either-or, but the two choices are consistent with each other.

Comment: How are they consistent with each other? Can show that in the form of an answer please?

Comment: The equation for $v$ does not contain the nozzle size. They are mathematically independent.

Comment: So, we can use $v$ = $sqrt$$2gh$?

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two approximations built into the analysis that ends with $v=\sqrt{2gh}$.

1. The velocity of the fluid at the surface is zero.  If your outlet is big enough that enough volume exits the jet to actually lower the surface at an appreciable velocity, this approximation breaks down.  The flow rates $v_1 A_1$ at the surface and $v_2 A_2$ at the jet should be equal.  If $A_2$ is significant compared to $A_1$, then $v_1$ is significant as compared to $v_2$.  If the jet is tiny this doesn't matter.
2. Viscosity will slow down the flow.  I don't remember the details, but I believe the Reynolds Number (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number) will tell if this is significant.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean by surface? 
and on the whole you mean that changing A will affect on the velocity ?

Comment: I meant upper surface, where the liquid touches air.  Both effects will cause the fluid velocity to depend on the nozzle cross sectional area when they come into play.